# Terminal commands to install R packages with Rcpp like in Rstudio?

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I'm recently moving from Rstudio to vim when working with R code. I'm having trouble understanding how to replicate the commands sent when I click `Install and Restart` in Rstudio.

As far as I understand, I need to run

```
Rscript -e "Rcpp::compileAttributes()"
Rscript -e "devtools::document()"
```

to replicate Rstudio's `Document` button. Then

```
Rscript -e "Rcpp::compileAttributes()"
R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source .
```

should replicate the `Install and Restart` button.

The problem is: Using Rstudio's buttons installs the package just fine, while running the commands wont. When trying to `document()` I get the following error:

```
Updating mypkg documentation
Writing NAMESPACE
Loading mypkg
Error in representation(N = "numeric", N_dep = "numeric", vertices = "list",  : could not find function "representation"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... source_many -> source_one -> eval -> eval -> setClass -> is
Execution halted
```

And if I ignore it and just install the package, the only object available in the package is `my_kpg::'.__t__[[:base'`. How can I construct a sequence of command line inputs that behave identically to Rstudio's `Document` and `Install and Restart` buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `Rscript` doesn't load the `methods` package by default while the interactive R session does (weird). The problem was caused by the missing package.

Adding `library(methods)` to my `.Rprofile` file solved the issue.